# I don't understand why boost::asio::read_until reads characters behind the delimiter

Tags: c++, boost, tcp

According to the `boost::asio::read_until` documentation:

> After a successful read_until operation, the streambuf may contain additional data beyond the delimiter. An application will typically leave that data in the streambuf for a subsequent read_until operation to examine.

I do not understand why this happens.

**Is it because, in the TCP protocol, if you do not read all the available characters, you can lose them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if it read only until the character you want, it would have to perform one one-character read at a time. This would be horribly inefficient.